# How can I sub-divide or split my 2D Array into smaller quadrants repeatedly?

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, split

I'm trying to split a 2^n by 2^n 2D array into 4 quadrants. I then want to search these quadrants for pieces of information. If all the quadrant array elements = 1 or 0, then that quadrant can be left alone. If the quadrant has a mix of 1's and 0's, then I want to carry on splitting the array until I am left with a quadrant of only 1's or 0's (Even if that's a single array element). I understand that I must implement a recursive function, but I can't seem to figure out how... Here's what I have so far. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
node* split(int **image_array, int width){
 node* root = NULL;
 int i, j;
 int black_pixel_NW = 0, black_pixel_NE = 0, black_pixel_SE = 0, black_pixel_SW = 0;


 if (width >= 2){


     for (i = 0; i < width/2; i++)   {
         for (j = 0; j < width/2; j++){
             printf("(%d,%d) = %d\n", i, j, image_array[i][j]);
             if (image_array[i][j] == 0){
                 black_pixel_NW = ++black_pixel_NW;
             }
         }
     }
     printf("\nBlack pixels NW = %d\n", black_pixel_NW);


     for (i = width/2; i < width; i++)   {
         for (j = 0; j < width/2; j++){
             printf("(%d,%d) = %d\n", i, j, image_array[i][j]);
             if (image_array[i][j] == 0){
                 black_pixel_NE = ++black_pixel_NE;
             }
         }
     }
     printf("\nBlack pixels NE = %d\n", black_pixel_NE);


             for (i = width/2; i < width; i++)   {
         for (j = width/2; j < width; j++){
             printf("(%d,%d) = %d\n", i, j, image_array[i][j]);
             if (image_array[i][j] == 0){
                 black_pixel_SE = ++black_pixel_SE;
             }
         }
     }
    printf("\nBlack pixels SE = %d\n", black_pixel_SE);


     for (i = 0; i < width/2; i++)   {
         for (j = width/2; j < width; j++){
             printf("(%d,%d) = %d\n", i, j, image_array[i][j]);
             if (image_array[i][j] == 0){
                 black_pixel_SW = ++black_pixel_SW;
             }
         }
     }
     printf("\nBlack pixels SW = %d\n", black_pixel_SW);

     width = width / 2;

 }

 return root;}
```

The code will be for reading a binary image file, hence the black_pixel variables. black_pixel_NW means number of black pixels in the upper left quadrant. I have pointer stuff in the function as this information will eventually be stored in a quad tree.

Comment: Every recursive function has 3 things: (1) the setup & test (the calculations & test whether your condition is satisfied, and the alteration of the arguments for the next call), (2) the recursive call with updated arguments, and (3) a way to return after your test in (1) is satisfied. Thinking through it in that manner will usually allow a solution. If you can't do all 3, then you can't use recursion for the task.

Comment: Also note: if `width, i, j and black_pixel_XX` cannot ever be negative, then choose a more appropriate datatype like `size_t` or `unsigned`. That will allow the compiler to help keep you out of trouble. (`printf` conversion specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`)

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is easiest to understand when breaking the function into its absolute barest state. You're actually writing the logic 4 times.

The most obvious solution(to me!) would be to expand the function parameters a bit. Something like:

```
split(int **img, int x, int y, int width, int height);
```

Putting your logic in for only a single quadrant, then recursing through each of the four quadrants. Like:

```
if (all_pixels_same_color) return; // or do something
else {
 split(img, x, y, width/2, height/2); // Top left Quadrant
 split(img, x + width/2, y, width/2, height/2); // Top right Q.
 split(img, x, y + height/2, width/2, height/2); // Bottom left Q.
 split(img, x + width/2, y + height/2, width/2, height/2); // Bottom right Q.
}
```

Now to look through each pixel of the image, just start with the full dimensions of the image

```
split(img, 0, 0, 256, 256);
```

The function will treat this as a quadrant, and most likely split into four more quadrants(calling itself four times with the four new starting quadrant locations).

EDIT:
And an example of checking all the pixels in a quadrant for the same value:

```
if (width == 1 || height == 1)
 return; // or something else

int i, j;
int cmp = img[x][y]; // top-left pixel

for (j = y; j < height; j++)
 for (i = x; i < width; i++)
   if (img[i][j * IMG_WIDTH] != cmp)
    goto split_to_quads; // or whatever
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the piece of code. Just reviewing the first part (with the four calls to split), and I'm trying to implement it. However, I'm not completely sure how to test each of the quadrants that are produced as a result of it. I tried using two for loops to search through the resultant quadrant, but this did not seem to work... I placed the two loops before the four calls to split, so it's very possible my placement is incorrect. Cheers!